# Data from dynamically created inputs table is not passing to backend

Tags: javascript, html, django, mongodb

I am trying to pass multiple data from an input table (with row addable option) in the backend for saving them in my database. Here I try to use **Django** and **MongoDB**.

My frontend's `JS` & `HTML` code is:

```js
let i = 1;
function rowTemplate(i) {
  return `<tr data-index=${i}>
      <td>${i}</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="name-${i}"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="roll-${i}"></td>
      <td><input type="email" name="email-${i}"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="password-${i}"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="address-${i}"></td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-times-circle" style="font-size: 22px; color: red;" onclick="removeRow(${i})"></i></td>
    </tr>`
}

for (i = 1; i <= 4; i ++) {
  $('.my_dynamic_table').append(rowTemplate(i));
}

function removeRow(i) {
  $(".my_dynamic_table").find(`tr[data-index='${i}']`).remove();
}

function addRow() {
  $('.my_dynamic_table').append(rowTemplate(i));
  i++;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container my-5">
    <h2>Welcome to dynamic input table with row adding option</h2>

    <form class="" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <table class="table table-hover my-5">
          <thead class="">
              <tr>
                  <th>No</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Roll</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
                  <th>Password</th>
                  <th>Address</th>
                  <th>Remove?</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="my_dynamic_table">
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="row m-0">
          <button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="addRow()">Add row</button>
          <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary ml-auto">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>

  </div>
</body>
  
<head>
    <title></title>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- animated css link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.0.0/animate.min.css"/>

    <!-- font awsome css link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- custom css link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="#">

</head>
```

Now how can I write my `views.py` in **Django** to receive all the data for saving them in the database? You may also check my project file: [link](https://github.com/Kanchon-Gharami/myProblems-Stackoverflow.git). I am trying to avoid **ajax** or other kinds of complex stuff. It will be very helpful for me if it can be done in a simple approach like the following:

```
def row_addable_table_view(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            this_name = request.POST['name']
            ...............
```

Here `this_name = request.POST['name-1']` may work for only 1st column. But I need all of them.

Comment: Why is your div above your head, and not inside a <body>?

Comment: Also your backend is not going to get a query string key of `name`.  It will get a query string key of `name-1`, `name-2`, etc.  That's how you are generating your html

Comment: my actual codes div are inside the body. For better code presenting purpose in the snippet, I try to use this kind of weird style. Actually, I am new in here..

Comment: imho, that's not "better code presenting".  It's majorly confusing.  Just show us your real code.

Comment: but how can I manage to use name-1, name-2 there?

Comment: `request.POST['name-1']` ?  I'm not familiar with django syntax, but you have to use the actual key some how

Comment: I can manage to take name-1, or name-2 , but how can I take all of them in a time.... Here l cannot use loop as     'name-x'     is inside quotations.